# Dependency injection in Specflow, is it one context object per feature?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, bdd, specflow

In Specflow it's possible to share context between step definitions using [dependency injection](http://specflow.org/getting-started/beyond-the-basics/)

Does this mean that you end up with a different "context" class for each feature?

If so, wouldn't this make it impractical to share step definitions across features? Do you assume fields have been set?

Comment: What do you mean by "Do you assume fields have been set"? Are you referring to private fields in the step files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that you end up with a different "context" class for each feature?

I don't think this would be the case. When writing a spec you will most certainly mention several "kind" of parts of your system. Let's say we have the following scenario:

```
Scenario: List todo items
  Given I'm registered as user@example.com
  And I'm logged in as user@example.com
  And I add a todo item with the text 'Listen to stackoverflow podcast'
  When I list all my todo items
  Then I should see the following items
    | Text                            | Completed |
    | Listen to stackoverflow podcast | false     |
```

In this case we're interacting with several parts of the system:

- Registration
- Authentication
- TodoItem creation
- TodoItem listing

When implementing the steps for this feature we'll probably end up with a step files organized like this:

- `AuthSteps`

  - `Given I'm registered as __`
  - `Given I'm logged in as __`
- `TodoItemsSteps`

  - `I add a todo item with the text '__'`
  - `When I list all my todo items`
  - `Then I should see the following items`

In this case using context injection we would want to share the value of `CurrentUser` to be able to say things like "When I list all **my** todo items", referring to the current user. This way any other steps in any other stepFile can be contextual of previous steps.

On the other hand, I wouldn't use context injection with the results of `When I list all my todo items` because the only steps that would share those feature specific concerns will be in the same feature file. You can have multiple variations of the `then` "statement", like `Then I should see n items`.

Although I do think you might have more than one class you use with using context injection to share dependencies of the services you're constructing, or maybe the services themselves (Storage, Session, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

IMHO you should use context based on 'domains' in your system, not based on the features in your test.

We have found that contexts like this provide good encapsulation of concerns and are more logical. So you might have a `UserContext`, `CartContext`, `PaymentContext` etc, and then your steps which need functions or data in these contexts ask for them in the constructor.

As Andreas said, specflow will manage your contexts so that they are isolated per scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime of the objects is per Scenario. This means, that you get for every Scenario/Test a separate instance.

This way you can not share a state between different tests, so they can not influence each other.

Answer (score 0):

It is not dependent on feature. Every scenario will have its own context and it will end as scenario ends , different features can use same context